# save state bootstrap-treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-treeview

I need to save the state with this component https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview
So I have modify the source code here: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-treeview.js

and I have added in the line 104 the code:

```
getNodes: $.proxy(this.getNodes, this),
```

and in the line 1209 the code:

```
Tree.prototype.getNodes= function (options) {
            console.log("--- getNodes ---");
           return this.nodes
     };
```

So when I execute the code :

```
var jsonData=x$(idTree).treeview('getNodes', { silent: true });
```

I have the JSON array.
But when Use this JSON array in the

```
var objTree=$("idTree").treeview({
      data: jsonData,         // data is not optional
       color: "#428bca",
             expandIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
              collapseIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
              //nodeIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark',
              showTags: true,
              enableLinks:true
    });
```

This generate problem in render tree in the outline...have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem:

my problem is the return value.. and this is correct way--> **this.tree**

```
Tree.prototype.getNodes= function (options) {
            console.log("--- getNodes ---");
           return this.tree
     };
```